# IF NOT EXISTS in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new in Oracle, need some help to SQL Server's **IF NOT EXISTS** equivalent in Oracle.
I need to find the max RoleID from Role table based on entity number if a particular role does not exists. I have created below query but its failing (**it should return null if an entity has that particular role and should return 1 if an entity has no role, its returning 1 in both cases**) if an entity does not have any role.

**Code:-**

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(role_id), 0) + 1 AS RoleID from roles WHERE entity_no = '000001'
AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM roles
        WHERE entity_no = '000001' AND name = 'Survey'
    )
```

I need 1 as RoleID if an entity does not have any role(s) but it should return null for the entity having that particular role('Survey') else return max RoleID with increment, TIA.

Comment: Other than maybe the call to `NVL()`, your query is ANSI compliant and should work on Oracle (and many other databases as well).

Comment: tried without NVL as well but getting same result if an entity has that role and for entity has no role.

Comment: Hi Sunil, what do you mean by "failing"?

Comment: hi @ekochergin, it should return null if an entity has that particular role and should return 1 if an entity has no role. Also updated the question.

Comment: If you are using this to generate a sequence then why not use a sequence? You may have to accept that there will be gaps in the sequence but it will be better than using `MAX` and having concurrency issues if two queries are started at the same time to generae the `MAX` and you end up with duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do? Read comments within code.

- entity_no = 00001 has Survey, so query should return NULL
- entity_no = 00002 doesn't have Survey, so query should return 1

---

```
SQL> with
  2  roles (role_id, entity_no, name) as
  3  -- sample data
  4    (select 1, '00001', 'Survey' from dual union all
  5     select 2, '00002', 'xxx'    from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8  -- does ENITITY_NO has role for NAME = Survey? If so, CNT = 1; else, CNT = 0
  9    (select entity_no,
 10            sum(case when name = 'Survey' then 1 else 0 end) cnt
 11     from roles
 12     group by entity_no
 13    )
 14  -- finally, check CNT value and return the result
 15  select case when t.cnt = 0 then 1 else null end as role_id
 16  from roles r join temp t on t.entity_no = r.entity_no
 17  where r.entity_no = '&par_entity_no';
Enter value for par_entity_no: 00001

   ROLE_ID
----------


SQL> /
Enter value for par_entity_no: 00002

   ROLE_ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: i think i made some confusion here, as per your example it should return null for 00001 as it has that role, should return 2 for 00002 (its max id), should return 1 for 00003.

Comment: Well, it can't return anything for 00003 as it doesn't exist yet. As of the rest of your comment, we agree - 00001 returns NULL. But, for 00002, shouldn't it actually return 3 (as its MAX ID + 1)? If so, then modify SELECT to `select nvl(r.role_id, 0) + case when ...` (basically, add NVL function call).